# Using JQuery "select option:first-child" just for an element with a given id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

This code looks at if dropdownlist with 'townid' has an option of Central and then puts Central after the first option at `all` dropdownlists.

```
 var central = $('#townid option:contains("Central")');
   if(central){
     central.insertAfter('select option:first-child');
   }
```

My problem is that:

How can I add it just after dropdownlist that has id of townid? I mean something like:

```
 var central = $('#townid option:contains("Central")');
   if(central){
     central.insertAfter('#townid select option:first-child');
   }
```

For example:

```
 <select id=townid>
    <option value="5000">AL</option>
    <option value="5001">NY</option>
    <option value="5002">LA</option>
    <option value="5003">NY</option>
    <option value="5204">Central</option>
    <option value="5024">FA</option>
 </select>

 <select id="someid">
    <option value="3002">Brooklyn</option>
    <option value="6001">Manhattan</option>
 </select>
```

After that process they should be seem like:

```
 <select id=townid>
    <option value="5000">AL</option>
    <option value="5204">Central</option>
    <option value="5001">NY</option>
    <option value="5002">LA</option>
    <option value="5003">NY</option>
    <option value="5024">FA</option>
 </select>

 <select id="someid">
    <option value="3002">Brooklyn</option>
    <option value="6001">Manhattan</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: @Mathias I gave an example of code.

Comment: Was this the reason why you wanted to use plain JavaScript? Because you could not get the selector to work?

Comment: @steffenbew already gave you the correct answer. You don't event need the `if` clause: `$('#townid option:contains("Central")').insertAfter('#townid option:first-child');`

Comment: if (central.length) is necessary because sometimes that dropdownlist doesn't contain Central, it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just messed up the selector, because #townid IS the select tag.

```
 var central = $('#townid option:contains("Central")');
   if(central.length === 1){
     central.insertAfter('#townid option:first-child');
   }
```

Comment: This answer won’t work. `if (central)` should be `if (central.length)`. (Same mistake as OP.)

Comment: Actually just I want to control if dropdownlist has an option named Central

Comment: `select#townid` should be `#townid` only.

Comment: @steffenbew, can you edit your your code as if (central.length)? Because it works.

Comment: To be precise, you should compare the length to an expected number.

Comment: I am accepting as an answer with considering my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add it just after dropdownlist that has id of `townid`?

Okay, I’m gonna assume your HTML looks something like this:

```
<select id="townid">
  <option>
    …
  </option>
</select>
```

In that case, you could use:

```
 $('#townid option:contains("Central")').appendTo('#townid option');
```

If there are multiple `option` elements inside `#townid` and you only want to select the first, just change the selector:

```
 $('#townid option:contains("Central")').appendTo('#townid option:first');
```

In your example, don’t use `if (central)`, use `if (central.length)` instead.

Comment: @Matt You’re right the `if` check is not needed — I was just saying that if you’re gonna use it anyway you should at least make sure that it works. Also, jQuery won’t “silently do nothing” — even if no elements are matched, it will still do more work compared to using the `if` check.

Comment: I have many dropdownlists and I want to do this just for the dropdownlist which has townid as id. I want to move the Central after the first option. It should make that move of Central just to the dropdownlist which has townid as id.

Comment: Voting up because of central.length suggestion.